# Vagrant error E_NOINTERFACE starting VirtualBox different versions in Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate (COM/DCOM error?)

Tags: windows, com, vagrant, virtualbox, dcom

I am trying to start VirtualBox (versions 5.1, 4.3.4, 4.16) in Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate via Vagrant 1.7.4 command

> 'vagrant up'

and i am getting error

> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>   Command: ["list", "hostonlyifs"]
>   Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_NOINTERFACE (0x80004002) - No such interface supported (extended info not available)
>   VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.

It looks like vagrant handles DCOM in a bad way.
I've added Group "Distributed COM Users" to VBoxSVC.exe, but no luck.
The group has both Local Access and Remote Access Permissions.

How could i fix it?

I do enabled access to VirtualBox to everyone as well as for Distributed COM users, but nothing works - i am still have

> Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66} aComponent={VirtualBox} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false

in VirtualBox log when i try to

> vagrant up

Comment: The same virtualBox distributives work just OK in Win 8.1.

Comment: when i start VBoxSVC.exe, i get log like this:

>VirtualBox (XP)COM Server 4.1.16 r78094 win.amd64 (May 22 2012 14:22:25) release log
00:00:00.000 main     Log opened 2016-01-14T12:10:26.031874700Z
00:00:00.000 main     OS Product: Windows Vista Ultimate Edition
00:00:00.000 main     OS Release: 6.0.6000
00:00:00.000 main     Executable: E:\sys\vm\VirtualBox.4.1.16\VBoxSVC.exe
00:00:00.000 main     Process ID: 5860
00:00:00.000 main     Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:00.437          VDInit finished

Comment: 00:08:24.616 Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66} aComponent={VirtualBox} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false

Comment: regardless of whether i start it as a current user or as administrator.

Comment: virtualBox.exe runs just OK and could start virtual OS images.

Answer (score 0):

did you check [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/643558/virtualbox-command-line-error) it says **not** to start cmd window as an Administrator

Comment: i did start command window as a user as well as admin, and it resulted the very same error. If i set VBoxSVC to be run only from admin in DCOM properties, the error was about required elevated privileges.
Beside all, i've checked my cmd user state with a script.

Comment: According to similar errors, it looks like incorrect or absent user rights of a registry key  or compatibility mode required or something similar dcom problem.

Comment: I do enabled access to VirtualBox to everyone as well as for Distributed COM users, but nothing works - i am still have
>Watcher  ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) aIID={c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66} aComponent={VirtualBox} aText={The object is not ready}, preserve=false